# using CreateAttribute function in VB 6.0 cannot remove first instance of CreateAttribute variable

Tags: xml, vb6

My code:

```
Set objnode = createnode OBJDOC, NOTHING, "TRANSMISSION")
createattribute objdoc, objnode, "xmlns", "http://www.irs.gov/efile"
Set objnode = createnode OBJDOC, objnode, "TransmissionHeader")
createattribute objdoc, objnode, "RecordCount", "1"
```

What my XML file looks like:

```
<transmission xmlns="http://www.irs.gov/efile">
<transmissionHeader xmlns="" RecordCount="1">
```

I don't know why xmlns="" appears on the second line.

Comment: Can we see the source for createnode and createattribute please?

Comment: These are functions out of a microsoft DLL  MSXML6.DLL

Answer (score 0):

Notice that `xmlns="..."` is *default namespace*. Descendant elements inherit ancestor default namespace implicitly (except in some certain conditions). How this has anything to do with your problem? Your expected XML is as follow :

```
<transmission xmlns="http://www.irs.gov/efile">
<transmissionHeader RecordCount="1">
```

Notice that in the above XML, `transmissionHeader` element is in namespace `"http://www.irs.gov/efile"`, the same namespace as its parent. So you need to **find a way to create XML element in namespace** using VB6 (I'm not familiar with VB6, unfortunately). Currently, your code create `transmissionHeader` element in no namespace (empty namespace), that's why default namespace declaration was reset to empty locally in that element :

```
<transmissionHeader xmlns="" RecordCount="1">
```

Comment: I understand what happened I was hoping for a way to Delete the xmlns reference and replace with recordcount so that the xmlns doesn't show up in the second line.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have a transcription error in what you posted for your code; I'd expect there to be opening parentheses as well as closing parentheses, but I only see the closing one on your function calls. Also, it doesn't really look like VB6 usage of MSXML6, as you're calling some global createNode instead of calling it on a document object. I'll take a shot at answering anyway, though.

It helps to think of an XML document as a tree structure, and there happens to be a standardized serialization of the tree which one can keep in files or send over the Internet or the like. But each node in the tree itself has a namespace. There's quite a bit to how namespaces work, but in the simplest case, when serialized to a file, the default namespace (represented by the "xmlns" attribute) applies to the element its on as well as its descendant elements.

The output you have indicates that the root element is in the `http://www.irs.gov/efile` namespace, but the child element is in the empty namespace, which leads me to think that your code creates the child element without a namespace. In order to output this, then, the XML library needs to put an empty xmlns attribute on the child, in order to show that the node is in the empty namespace.

When manipulating the document tree programmatically, you don't want to manage the xmlns attributes directly. The standard MSXML6 [`createNode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757901%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API has a `namespaceURI` parameter for specifying the namespace for that node. What I think you're looking for is to create all your element nodes throughout your document with the correct namespaceURI. Then, when the document is written out to a file or web server or wherever, the XML library will automatically figure out that the most compact way to represent the namespaces in the output is to just use an xmlns attribute on the root element specifying the namespace for all elements in the document, and not have a separate xmlns attribute on the other attributes.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Yes, we did leave out the left ( ,  in the sample.  When looking at createNode API we get the following parameters:  createnode (dom60type,parent,"nodename","nodevalue")  with no namespaceURI.  Our Project...References... only includes Micosoft XML, V.6.0 (msxml6.dll) for handling XML file creations. In addition the xmlns- only appears when we add the CreateAttribute function for a node.  Thanks again for your help.